# Going into graphical user interface on OpenIndiana

Tags: unix, solaris, opensolaris, openindiana

There was an error: 
application/desktop-cache/gio-module-cache:default failed fatally
After that, expected something like: 
https://distrowatch.com/images/cgfjoewdlbc/openindiana.png
But while there were the Firefox and Thunderbird icons on the upper taskbar, the terminal icon to the right of those is missing.
The icons that should be on the upper right when I am logged in are missing.
No icons at the bottum.

I am using OpenIndiana Hipster on a Dell Dimension 4600. Should I have gotten an earlier version of Illumos?

Answer (score 1):

Please report your issue on the tracker or the mailing lists:
- https://www.openindiana.org/bugs
- https://www.openindiana.org/mailman

OpenIndiana developers do not follow this forum so you have very little chance to get help here.
You need to provide the version you use and information about your hardware.

Kind regards